# What is the difference between pyc and pyo files in Python?

Tags: python, compilation

I see that .pyc and .pyo file are both compiled python code. What is difference between them and when I should use one or another?

Comment: py*C*: *C*ompiled, py*O*: *O*ptimized, if you can't remember.

Answer (score 14):

`.pyc` files are python files compiled to byte code by the interpreter.  They are generated normally when a file is imported.

`.pyo` are compiled byte code without line numbers, assertions, and some other things (possibly doc strings) for optimization purposes.

when invoking the python interpreter, you may pass the `-O` or `-OO` option to generate a `.pyo` file.  Using `-O` will throw out the line numbers, assertions, and  some debugging info.  `-OO` will result in a `.pyo` file also stripped of docstrings.

Comment: I've been searching forever for the distinction between .pyo and .pyc files.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `.pyo` and `.pyc` is that `.pyo` is optimised and that means that you will not be able to use certain features like docstrings. `.pyc` is the whole deal, with no limitations.

Comment: `.pyo` files will contain docstrings if created with `-O`, they will not have docstrings when using `-OO`